# Windows Phone 8.1 throws NullReferenceException when press backbutton

Tags: navigation, windows-phone-8.1

I have an app that use many xaml pages.

Ex: Home Page ==> Book Title ==> Chapter Number ==> Reader (Webview)

The problem is, when I navigate from Chapter Number to WebView, I pass a parameter. Ex: Frame.Navigate(typeof(Reader), chapter).

Until now everything is ok.

The problem is when I´m in Reader and press the BackButton, the app crash with a NullReferenceException.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code you use when you click on the BackButton ?

Comment: what exception you get? and also post the code where exception is occurring..

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use this in Reader page  

  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
            HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
  }


        private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {

           if (webView.CanGoBack)
           {
               e.Handled = true;
           }
        }

Don't Forgot to manage back event in application.
```